# jQuery deferred: "then" ... "when" ... where's the "join" or "blockUntilDone"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jaydata

I'm using the JayData.js library. It works quite well. However, I have a few situations where I've got a toArray() call deep in the function tree. Rather than trying to access my "busy" signal from there, I'd just as soon have the method block. Is that possible? I'm picturing something like "context.Groups.toArray(myObservableVar).block()".

Update 1: It appears that the JayData library returns a jQuery deferred object judging from the use of "then" and "when" operators on the return value. Is there a corresponding method to "join" -- meaning wait for the finish?

Comment: There is [when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to combine callbacks and Deferred instances...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `blockUntilDone()` method would go against the principles of deferred execution and continuations. JayData's `toArray()` is asynchronous *because* it is designed not to block the caller.

If you want this kind of code:

```
// Initialize context and groups...

var arrayOfGroups = context.Groups.toArray();  // Want synchronous behavior.

// Do something with 'arrayOfGroups'...
```

Trying to block until the deferred is resolved is not the solution. Move the last part of your code into a callback passed to `toArray()` instead:

```
// Initialize context and groups...

context.Groups.toArray(function(arrayOfGroups) {
    // Do something with 'arrayOfGroups'...
});
```

Alternatively, bind to the returned promise with [done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) or [then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

```
context.Groups.toArray().done(function(arrayOfGroups) {
    // Do something with 'arrayOfGroups'...
});
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it helped me to understand that Javascript is more like a dual-threaded model than a multi-threaded model.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed JayData toArray() (and all relevant data returning or saving/updating method) implements jQuery deferred. As from 1.0.5 you have to include the JayDataModules/deferred.js in order to this functionality to work.

For your use case `$.when` might be an answer:

```
var customers = context.Customers.toArray();
var products = context.Products.toArray();
var suppliers = context.Suppliers.toArray();

$.when(customers, products, suppliers).then(function(customers, products, suppliers) {
   //we have everything here
   //notice the the parameter names are shadowed as the var customers variable only
   //holds a promise not the value
  customers.forEach( ... );
  products[12].ProductName = "X";
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming that JayData uses jQuery Deferred objects.